# how to remove Jsessionid in url ?iam using was6.1 RAD IDE,Java

Tags: jsessionid

I need to remove **jsessionid** from the URL.

> i am working in was 6.1 and java.Is there any way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache URL Rewrite,
see if this helps you: http://atgkid.blogspot.in/2011/11/issues-with-jsessionid-in-url.html